# broadcasting a data structure to the network

Tags: arrays, json, algorithm, networking, data-structures

I have a data structure I want to broadcast to the network for others to download for free. This data structure holds information about a more complex data structure used in a program that the other network participants are also running.

What is the best way to encode this data such that I reduce overhead of transmitting over the wire?

For example, the "full" data structure will look something like this:

```
fullData = array(
    0 => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 77, 6),
    1 => array(89, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    2 => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    3 => array(102, 22, 16, 4, 5, 6),
    4 => array(1, 2, 55, 4, 5, 27)...
```

...and so on and so forth.

The data I'm broadcasting will be essentially an index of the "important" data in this array - so "lightweight" nodes on the network are not tasked with parsing gigabytes of data looking for the important info - my "master" program does that for them. However I need to report to the network the "important" data so I'm thinking of encoding an array such as this:

```
importantData = array(
    0 => array(4),
    1 => array(0),
    3 => array(0, 1, 2),
    4 => array(2, 5)...
```

...and so on and so forth.

Is JSON a good way to encode this data and send it? I want to save as much as possible on transmission costs, unless another parameter is more costly as far as disk space or CPU cycles goes (on my server as well as the other nodes). How can I be sure I am approaching this problem in the correct way?

Comment: JSON is relatively lightweight when compared to XML, but you need to determine what your endpoints will be. If you are always sending to a particular platform, there binary formats much lighter than either. JSON and XML are best used when you need a lot of flexibility, e.g. communicating between a PHP and ASP.net server.

Comment: Depends on what your data can be at maximum (both keys & values), but a simple binary protocol like bmasterson suggest (which could be <byte of index><byte of important value>(<byte of another important value>)<seperator (null byte perhaps><byte of next idx...` seems about as efficient as you can get.